# ImageScanner.ScanFilesToFolderAsync throws HRESULT 0xE8E2DD73 randomly

Tags: c#, uwp

This is a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) application for Windows 10 written in C# whose purpose is to scan documents using the following class:

```
Windows.Devices.Scanners.ImageScanner
```

And in the line:

```
// Scan API call to start scanning from the Feeder source of the scanner.
ImageScannerScanResult isr = await myScanner.ScanFilesToFolderAsync(ImageScannerScanSource.Feeder, folder);
```

I get the following exception:

```
System.Exception: Exception from HRESULT: 0xE8E2DD73
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at MyProject.ScannerPage.<ScanToFolder>d__11.MoveNext()
```

This exception is being thrown randomly: sometimes, the line of code I said works successfully, sometimes it fails and I haven't detect a pattern or condition that causes it to fail.

The only hint I get is "HRESULT: 0xE8E2DD73" (in other computer the HRESULT code is: 0x904427B5), but I have been unable to find the meaning of that HRESULT code.

So, I wonder if any of you have a workaround for this issue or a different approach to perform this operation.

This is the full code:

```
try
{
    // Get the scanner object for this device id
    ImageScanner myScanner = await ImageScanner.FromIdAsync(deviceId);

    // Check to see if the use has already cancelled the scenario
    if (model.ScenarioRunning)
    {
        if (myScanner.IsScanSourceSupported(ImageScannerScanSource.Feeder))
        {
            // Set MaxNumberOfPages to zero to scanning all the pages that are present in the feeder
            myScanner.FeederConfiguration.MaxNumberOfPages = 0;

            cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

            // Scan API call to start scanning from the Feeder source of the scanner.
            ImageScannerScanResult operation = await myScanner.ScanFilesToFolderAsync(ImageScannerScanSource.Feeder, folder);

            model.ScenarioRunning = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // The selected scanner does not have a Feeder
            model.ScenarioRunning = false;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Utils.OnScenarioException(ex, model);
}
```

Comment: Have you ever tried to add a "cancel the scan" job into your code? Is there any possible that something sometimes causes your scanner to fail? (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt204546.aspx)

Comment: Yes panda, I tried with the cancellationToken and it happens the same. Regardless of the "cancel the scan" the HRESULT is thrown randomly and the only info I have so far is the code number (which I don't know what means yet). So, "what causes my scanner to fail" is exactly what I would like to know.

Comment: After getting support from the manufacturer, it has been concluded that the problem resides in the WIA driver, which is developed by Microsoft. So, I either have to get a WIA supported scanner or a third-party library for ISIS or TWAIN.